# How to Update SQL Server Table With Data From Other Source (DataTable)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, datatable, sqlbulkcopy

I have a `DataTable` which is generated from .xls table.

I would like to store this `DataTable` into an existing table in SQL Server database.

I use `SqlBulkCopy` to store rows which have **unique PK**.

Problem is, I also have other rows which have **same PK** as SQL Server table but contain **cells with different value** compared to SQL Server table.

In short:

Let's say in my `DataTable` I have a row like this:

id(PK) | name | number

005    | abc  | 123

006    | lge  | 122

For my SQL server I have sth like this;

id(PK) | name | number

004    | cbs  | 345

005    | lks  | 122

Now you see the row **006** can be uploaded straight away into SQL Server using `SqlBulkCopy`. On the other hand the row **005** can't be inserted using it since SQL server table contains row with identical PK.

Now I tried to manually extract the row. Extract each single cell into an ArrayList then generate an UPDATE Table statement afterwards. However this method seems to be unfeasible as I have so many rows to process.

I am looking for a better method to achieve this goal.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank's

Comment: Can someone help me to format the table? I hope it doesn't look too confusing.

Comment: You say you want a successful implementation, but you don't explain *what* exactly you want to happen for `id` of "005".  Do you want to overwrite the data in the database table?  Or just ignore it from the `DataTable`?

Comment: Why don't you use XML format and Stored Procedure. The flow is.. you prepare XML data from DataTable, then pass to Stored Procedure. In SP, you can read XML as table. Then you can check which IDs are already in Table or not. Insert new data, update or ignore existing Ids.

Comment: What I try so far is generate a dynamic Update Table command. Sth like: update name=sth number =sth where id=sth . But as stated in my question I found this method to be unfeasible, therefore I am looking for a better method.

Comment: @Thit interesting suggestion. It's something worthed to try, I guess. If you are quite sure about an answer, just simply shoot it. Cheers & Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code:

C# Side code for reading data from DataTable and preparing the XML data:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append("<R>");
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    sb.Append("<C><ID>" + dt.Rows[0].ToString() + "</ID>");
    sb.Append("<N>" + dt.Rows[1].ToString() + "</N>");
    sb.Append("<I>" + dt.Rows[2].ToString() + "</I></C>");
}

sb.Append("</R>");

///pass XML string to DB side
///
//sb.ToString(); //here u get all data from data table as xml format
```

Database side Stored Procedure (you will need to update your table name):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateData 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @data       XML
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- keep data into temp table
    create table #tmp_data (id nchar(2),name varchar(20), number int)

    DECLARE @XMLDocPointer INT  
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @XMLDocPointer OUTPUT, @DATA

    INSERT INTO #tmp_data(id,name,number)
    SELECT  ID,N,I
    FROM OPENXML(@XMLDocPointer,'/R/C',2)
    WITH(
            ID  nchar(30),
            N   VARCHAR(20),
            I   int
        )

    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @XMLDocPointer

    begin tran
        -------------------INSERT not existing ones
        INSERT INTO TABLE (id,name,number)
        SELECT id,name,number
        FROM #tmp_data
        WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1
            FROM TABLE
            WHERE ID = #tmp_data.ID
        )

        --- update existing ones
        UPDATE  TABLE
        SET name = #tmp_data.name, number = #tmp_data.number
        FROM #tmp_data
        WHERE #tmp_data.id = TABLE.id

        commit tran

    if(@@error <> 0)
        rollback tran

END
```