# arraylist in insert query

Tags: java, sql

i am trying to insert data from excel sheet into database in java. for that i have connected both the database using ODBC. excelsheet has 2 columns cname and title.
after querying the Excel spreadsheet i stored the resultSet values of cname and title into  arraylist.

```
      List Cname = new  ArrayList();
      List Title=new ArrayList();

            Cname.add(rs.getString("Cname"));
            Title.add(rs.getString("Title"));
```

this will result like this

```
      [aaa, bbb,cccc, dddd]
      [tree,human,animal,bird]
```

when i try to insert  this into SQL database using insert query it is getting stored like this.

```
    statement1.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO dbo.company (Cname,Title)  SELECT      
   '"+Cname+"','"+Title+"'");


       Cname                               Title

    [aaa, bbb,cccc, dddd]        [tree,human,animal,bird]
```

but i want to store this as

```
      Cname               Title
     ___________________________
      aaa                  tree
      bbb                 human
      cccc                animal
      ddd                  bird
```

how do i do this???pls help to solve in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to insert/update the *list values*, actually you're inserting the string representations of the entire lists..

Assuming, both lists do exist (not null) and have the same length, then this is a trivial solution:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Cname.size(); i++ {
   statement1.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO dbo.company (Cname,Title)  SELECT      
     '"+Cname.get(i)+"','"+Title.get(i)+"'");
}
```

*Note* - every java class has an implementation of the `toString()` method, and that method is called, when you "use an object as a string", like in the expression to create the SQL statement. For lists, the method returns a String that simply includes the (String-representations of) the list element in brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Put a `for` loop around your insert statement:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Cname.size(); i++)
    statement1.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO dbo.company (Cname,Title) values ( '"+Cname.get(i)+"','"+Title.get(i)+"')");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your db is SQL Server, you can reference the followng Q & A. Just prepare xml data and pass to Stored Procedure.

[How to Update SQL Server Table With Data From Other Source (DataTable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222240/how-to-update-sql-server-table-with-data-from-other-source-datatable/9222483#9222483)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single SQL statement of this form:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.company (Cname, Title) 
VALUES ('aaa', 'tree'), 
       ('bbb', 'human'),
       ('cccc', 'animal'),
       ('dddd', 'bird')
```

With JDBC:

```java
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.append("INSERT INTO dbo.company (Cname,Title) VALUES ");

String glue = "";
for (int i = 0; i < Cname.size(); i++) {
  sql.append(glue);
  sql.append("('");
  sql.append(Cname.get(i).toString().replace("'", "''"));
  sql.append("', '");
  sql.append(Title.get(i).toString().replace("'", "''"));
  sql.append("')");
  glue = ", ";
}

statement1.executeUpdate(sql.toString());
```

An alternative syntax (if the above doesn't work for Excel spreadsheets) is this:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.company (Cname, Title) 
SELECT 'aaa', 'tree' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'bbb', 'human' UNION ALL
SELECT 'cccc', 'animal' UNION ALL
SELECT 'dddd', 'bird'
```

Or with JDBC

```java
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.append("INSERT INTO dbo.company (Cname,Title) ");

String glue = "";
for (int i = 0; i < Cname.size(); i++) {
  sql.append(glue);
  sql.append("SELECT '");
  sql.append(Cname.get(i).toString().replace("'", "''"));
  sql.append("', '");
  sql.append(Title.get(i).toString().replace("'", "''"));
  sql.append("'");
  glue = " UNION ALL ";
}

statement1.executeUpdate(sql.toString());
```